# Drop Down CSS menu children showing up over parent menu option

Tags: css

This is pretty frustrating, I've tried a variety of tricks to get this to work.

This CSS menu's children aspects are showing up over the main manu, I'm not sure why it's not doing just a normal drop down underneath.

Apparently I can't post an image since I'm new. Sorry! I hope you understand my explanation of it. When you hover over a parent menu item, the dropdown doesn't actually drop down starting at underneath the parent. Instead, it starts parallel and at the same height as the parent, meaning it obscures the parent menu option so you can't see it.

```
    /*Primary nav*/

#menu {
    background: #0072BC;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #efefef;
    border-top: 3px solid #efefef;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;



}
#menu ul, .navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 62.5em;


}
#menu ul li, .navbar ul li {
    display:block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#menu ul li a, .navbar li a, .navbar li a:visited {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .75em;
}
#menu ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: .9em;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #0072BC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#menu {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}



ul#menu ul {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
    width: 10.000em;
}
ul#menu ul ul, ul#menu ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
ul#menu ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
ul#menu a {
    background: #efefef;
    color: #666666;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 1%;
    padding: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul ul {
    display: none;
    left: -0.063em;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 270px;
    z-index: 100;
}
#menu ul ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu ul ul li a {
}
#menu ul ul ul, #menu ul ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: -0.063em;
}
#menu ul a:hover, #menu ul li:hover a, #menu ul li.iehover a, #menu ul li.current-menu-item a, #menu ul li.current-menu-item a:visited {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #efefef;
    color: #333;
}
#menu ul li:hover li a, #menu ul li.iehover li a, #menu ul li:hover li:hover li a, #menu ul li.iehover li.iehover li a, #menu ul li:hover li:hover li:hover li a, #menu ul li.iehover li.iehover li.iehover li a, #menu ul li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li a, #menu ul li.iehover li.iehover li.iehover li:hover li a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #efefef;
    color: #0072BC;
    float: none;
    font-size: .8em;
    padding: .5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 100;


}
#menu ul li:hover li a:hover, #menu ul li:hover li:hover a, #menu ul li.iehover li a:hover, #menu ul li.iehover li.iehover a, #menu ul li:hover li:hover li a:hover, #menu ul li:hover li:hover li:hover a, #menu ul li.iehover li.iehover li a:hover, #menu ul li.iehover li.iehover li.iehover a, #menu ul li:hover li:hover li:hover li a:hover, #menu ul li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a, #menu ul li.iehover li.iehover li.iehover li a:hover, #menu ul li.iehover li.iehover li.iehover li.iehover a, #menu ul li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li a:hover, #menu ul li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a, #menu ul li.iehover li.iehover li.iehover li.iehover li a:hover, #menu ul li.iehover li.iehover li.iehover li.iehover li.iehover a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #efefef;
    color: #333;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul ul, #menu ul li:hover ul ul ul, #menu ul li:hover ul ul ul ul, #menu ul li.iehover ul ul, #menu ul li.iehover ul ul ul, #menu ul li.iehover ul ul ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul, #menu ul ul li:hover ul, #menu ul ul ul li:hover ul, #menu ul ul ul ul li:hover ul, #menu ul li.iehover ul, #menu ul ul li.iehover ul, #menu ul ul ul li.iehover ul, #menu ul ul ul ul li.iehover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle of it.

Comment: You should add the HTML or a jsfiddle to give us a sample to work with.

Comment: or at least provide the html

Comment: ...or there's lots of examples out on the net of this exact functionality you could either just build off of to suit your specific needs, or at least compare to. :)

Comment: All- Thank you for your help. This website is AMAZING! I've stumbled across it before but never used it. That jsfiddle site is awesome.

In the future I'll be sure to do that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your submenu has `position:absolute;`, which defaults to `top:0`. Try this CSS:

```
#menu ul li {
    height:50px;
}

#menu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:0;
}
```

Notice I gave the top menu items a specific height, so that you could place the submenu that exact height from the top. Also, notice I gave both a `top` and `left` declaration for the submenu; proper `position:absolute;` usage requires both an X and Y placement. Browsers have default of `0` for both, but animations on Firefox will bork if you don't have both declared explicitly.

**Side Note**

I don't have a lot of time to go into everything, but you should really give your items a class and use the class as a selector, rather than rely on all that parent child crap. It would make your CSS something like this:

```
.MainMenuItem {
    height:50px;
}

.SubMenu {
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:0;
}
```

Just food for thought.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! I totally agree on the class aspects. I didn't write the original code, just dealing with ensuring it's fixed.